# How to make sure my pages from website has a preview with thumbnail when shared on telegram app?

Tags: wordpress, telegram

I realised that pages from my wordpress site does not have a preview (with thumbnail) when it is shared on telegram. Need some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[OG plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/og/) resolves this problem automatically.